# jq flatten list of objects into one object

Tags: jq

I want to go from

```json
[
  {"key_skjdghkbs": "deep house"},
  {"key_kjsskjbgs": "deadmau5"},
  {"key_jhw98w4hl": "progressive house"},
  {"key_sjkh348vg": "swedish house mafia"},
  {"key_js3485jwh": "dubstep"},
  {"key_jsg587jhs": "escape"}
]
```

to

```json
{
  "key_skjdghkbs": "deep house",
  "key_kjsskjbgs": "deadmau5"
  "key_jhw98w4hl": "progressive house",
  "key_sjkh348vg": "swedish house mafia",
  "key_js3485jwh": "dubstep",
  "key_jsg587jhs": "escape"
}
```

Each object in the original list has exactly one key but the keys are unique.

I could do something like `jq .[] .genre` if the keys were the same but they're not.

Answer (score 5):

[jq's add function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#add) does exactly this

```
jq 'add'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (assuming your file is named `so72297039.json`):

```sh
jq '[.[] | to_entries] | flatten | from_entries' < so72297039.json
```

(Edit: OP edited question, so here's relevant answer)

Comment: Ahh I forgot about this when creating my example. My keys are all actually unique. Can you take a look at the example again?

Comment: @SaiSunku sure, here's my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since duplicate keys are not possible (see other answer) you can use to format like this:

```
{
  "artist": [
    "deadmau5",
    "swedish house mafia"
  ],
  "genre": [
    "deep house",
    "progressive house",
    "dubstep"
  ],
  "song": [
    "escape"
  ]
}
```

with a `jq` call like this:

```
jq '
    map(to_entries)
    | flatten
    | group_by(.key)
    | map({key: first.key, value: map(.value)})
    | from_entries
' input.json
```

If the keys `artist`, `genre`, `song` are known in advance an easier to understand expression can be used.

Comment: Ahh I forgot about this when creating my example. My keys are all actually unique. Can you take a look at the question again?

Comment: In that case @SaiSunku 's answer is the best :-)